# Class type Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

It has been long time I did not use c++ and I have some basic errors. Can you tell me why I get Segmentation Fault from my generic code?
When I use int as a array type, it works perfectly but when I change it with "Trapdoor" type, it gives me Seg Fault.

```
array<array<int, colN>, rowN> SmartIds::createMatrix() {
    array<array<int, colN> , rowN> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < rowN; i++) {
        a[i] = createTrapdoors();
    }
//sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    return a;
}
```

Below code generates seg fault

```
array<array<Trapdoor, colN>, rowN> SmartIds::createMatrix() {
    array<array<Trapdoor, colN> , rowN> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < rowN; i++) {
        a[i] = createTrapdoors();
    }
//sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    return a;
}
```

I call my function like below;

```
auto i = createMatrix();
```

Trapdoor.cpp class

```
#include "Trapdoor.h"
#include <cryptopp/pwdbased.h>
using namespace std;
Trapdoor::Trapdoor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    key = nullptr;
    seed = nullptr;
    iv = nullptr;
    counter = 0;
}

Trapdoor::Trapdoor(byte* keyy, byte* ivv) {
    key = keyy;
    seed = keyy;
    iv = ivv;
    counter = 0;
}

Trapdoor::~Trapdoor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
    delete iv;
    delete key;
    delete seed;
}

void Trapdoor::deriveKeywithCounter() {
    SecByteBlock derived(32);
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA1> kdf;
    //kdf.DeriveKey(derived.data(), derived.size(), 0, (byte*)b->data(), sizeof(b), NULL, 0, 100);

    memset(iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    counter++;

}

int Trapdoor::getCounter() {
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Probably `Trapdoor` does not implement value semantics properly. Show the class definition and the constructors/destructor code for `Trapdoor`.

Comment: I added my Trapdoor.cpp file to the question @MattMcNabb

Comment: @GüngörBasa, see [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Trapdoor` class does not have a correct copy-constructor or copy-assignment operator.  So when objects are copied by value, the old and the new both have destructor called and pointers are freed twice etc. etc.

It's rarely a good design to have your class be calling `delete` on things that it did not `new`.  Your code needs to be clear about who is responsible for freeing memory.

Usually, the best solution is to code `Trapdoor` so that it actually does not require any `delete` at all; then you do not have to write any special functions. See [Rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  (I will update this post to include a code sample if you show your class definition).

Comment: also, `delete iv;` etc. is almost certainly bugged; space allocated by `new[]` should be deleted with `delete[]` .